# javascript raphael object function passing

Tags: javascript, raphael

I apologize for asking this question but I am just looking for a little guidance on this morning. I simply want to create a function so that way I can make a Raphael element glow by just passing in that element. Below is the code I have. Why does this not work?

```
var paper = Raphael("playarea", 500, 500);

var rectangle = paper.rect(100, 100, 200, 200, 4);

function elemHover(var el)
{

    el.hover(
    // When the mouse comes over the object //
    // Stock the created "glow" object in myCircle.g
   function() {
    this.g = this.glow({
        color: "#0000EE",
         width: 10,
         opacity: 0.8
     });
    },
    // When the mouse goes away //
    // this.g was already created. Destroy it!
    function() {
     this.g.remove();
    });
}

elemHover(rectangle);
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aZG6C/15/

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your JS console?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle demo ?

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aZG6C/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `fill` the element( rectangle in our case) to trigger the hover.

```
rectangle.attr("fill", "red");
```

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aZG6C/17/

The full code will look like

```
<div id="playarea"></div>

​<script type="text/javascript">
var paper = Raphael("playarea", 500, 500);

var rectangle = paper.rect(100, 100, 200, 200, 4);

function elemHover(el)
{
    el.hover(
    // When the mouse comes over the object //
    // Stock the created "glow" object in myCircle.g
    function() {
     this.g = this.glow({
         color: "#0000EE",
         width: 10,
         opacity: 0.8
     });
    },
    // When the mouse goes away //
    // this.g was already created. Destroy it!
    function() {
     this.g.remove();
    });
}

rectangle.attr("fill", "red");

elemHover(rectangle);

</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Update**

Hover event is triggered only if the element is filled with something. If you want to have a transparent element you can try

```
rectangle.attr("fill", "transparent");
```

Check the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/aZG6C/20/

Comment: its great that it works but I don't understand why the rectangle.attr is required in order for this to work.

Comment: Hover event is triggered only if the element is filled with something. Answer updated with this information and a workaround for transparent element.

Comment: didn't know that. appreciate the help. you saved a computer today. feel good about it.